# How to position Material-UI component horizontally

Tags: html, material-ui

I have `MenuList` and a `Grid`. Unfortunately they are positioned vertically, top-down, but I need them left-right. Why is div as nesting element used for `Grid` in rendered HTML? How can I use the two components not a block but like floating HTML elements?

All I did I read carefully `Grid` documentation, but I did not found any useful info: https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

```
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <Grid container spacing={1} direction="column" alignItems="center" justify="center" style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
        <Grid item>
          <ButtonGroup size="small" aria-label="small outlined button group">
            <Button>Buy</Button>
            <Button>Sell</Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

I tried add `display="inline"` to `Grid`, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add *display: flex* to the parent div:

```
  <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
```

also, delete the *minHeight: 100vh* from Grid style:

```
  <Grid container spacing={1} direction="column" alignItems="center" justify="center">
```

Your component should look like that:

```
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}> // flex direction: row is not a must because row is the default
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <Grid container spacing={1} direction="column" alignItems="center" justify="center">
        <Grid item>
          <ButtonGroup size="small" aria-label="small outlined button group">
            <Button>Buy</Button>
            <Button>Sell</Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```